# a call to GetMessage causes a thread to stop

Tags: c++builder

I am writing a multi-threaded application using Borland C++ (Delphi Forms).  I have recently learned that I can use Windows' Messaging Service within these classes when I call the PostThreadMessage() function:

```
System = new STSystem(SystemName,1000,1,NULL);
while (PostThreadMessage(System->ThreadID,ST_MSG_SYSTEM_INIT,0,0) == 0)
{
    Sleep(0);
};
```

The above seems to work just fine.  The issue lies on the retrieval end of this process inside of the Thread Execution function:

```
void __fastcall STSystem::Execute()

{
    ST_Message STMSG;
    while(FStatus != Destroyed)
    {
        FHeartBeat++;
        if(GetMessage(MSG,NULL,ST_MSG_SYSTEM_START,ST_MSG_SYSTEM_END))
        {
            STMSG.Value = MSG->wParam;
            if((STMSG.dSYS + (8*STMSG.dSEC) + (64*STMSG.dDEP)) == FSystemID)
            {
                RXMessages[RxQueueIn++] = STMSG.MSG;    //  Message
                RXMessages[RxQueueIn++] = MSG->lParam;  //  Data
            }
        }
        if(TaskList->Count>0)
            ProcessTask();
        if(RxQueueIn!=RxQueueOut)
            ProcessRxMessage();
        if(TxQueueIn!=TxQueueOut)
            ProcessTxMessage();
        Sleep(0);
    };
}
```

The above works for about two thread cycles and then stops; the thread stops, not the program.  I have tried using the PeekMessage() function instead of the GetMessage() function in the IF clause following the FHeartbeat++ counter.  This prevents the thread from stopping however, the INIT message sent in the first block of code is still not found.

I hope this example is not too specific.  I have tried to leave in anything that was pertinent.  Basically, this is a message pump for a class that has no window.

Answer (score 1):

`GetMessage()` blocks the calling thread when there are no messages to retrieve.  Like Luis said, you need to make sure the thread has a message queue before you start posting messages to it, and you need to check the return value of `PostThreadMessage()` for failures.  A message queue is not created in a thread until any user32.dll function is called within the thread for the first time.  For example:

```
System = new STSystem(SystemName,1000,1,NULL);
while (!System->Ready)
   Sleep(100);
if (!PostThreadMessage(System->ThreadID,ST_MSG_SYSTEM_INIT,0,0))
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    //...
}
```

```
void __fastcall STSystem::Execute()
{
    // create a message queue
    PeekMessage(MSG, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
    Ready = true;

    ST_Message STMSG;
    while(FStatus != Destroyed)
    {
        FHeartBeat++;
        if(GetMessage(MSG,NULL,ST_MSG_SYSTEM_START,ST_MSG_SYSTEM_END)) // or PeekMessage()
        {
            STMSG.Value = MSG->wParam;
            if((STMSG.dSYS + (8*STMSG.dSEC) + (64*STMSG.dDEP)) == FSystemID)
            {
                RXMessages[RxQueueIn++] = STMSG.MSG;    //  Message
                RXMessages[RxQueueIn++] = MSG->lParam;  //  Data
            }
        }
        if(TaskList->Count>0)
            ProcessTask();
        if(RxQueueIn!=RxQueueOut)
            ProcessRxMessage();
        if(TxQueueIn!=TxQueueOut)
            ProcessTxMessage();
        Sleep(0);
    };
}
```

Comment: Like this:      while(PeekMessage(MSG, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE) != 0)
    {
        Sleep(0);
    };

Comment: You don't need to call PeekMessage() in a loop when creating the message queue. You only need to
call it once.

Answer (score 0):

To send messages to a tread it must have a message queue,  in the remarks section of this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx
you can fine the steps reqired to create a message queue for a thread.
By the way, if PostThreadMessage returns 0 (FALSE), there is an error and you must check the value returned by GetLastError.

Comment: while(PeekMessage(MSG, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE) != 0)
    {
        Sleep(0);
    };